# Im looking for a code wherein if i will click a button the exact time that i clicked the button will display in a table

Tags: php

I had a project and it's driving me crazy 'cous im not really good in programming . I had a registration form and a table where all the list of registered students will display . my problem is i had to display in the table the time they had registered . Automatically once they click the button, the time will display in the table.  please help me . Thanks a lot

Comment: I'm guessing you have a database? Then just save the date/time in the database as well. If you want more specifics, you need to give us more information and share some code. Right now, it's a bit too broad.

Comment: Using emojis in your question is highly unprofessional. Please do not be lazy. Make an attempt!

Answer (score -2):

get the timestamp with javascript using [Date.now()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now).

or

get the timestamp with php using [new DateTime()](http://php.net/manual/de/datetime.gettimestamp.php).

or

just create a [date/time field](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html) in your database table. so every entry will add the timestamp by itself.

I recommend you to just save this timestamp. You can convert it to human readable time format anytime you need.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question asked.

Comment: _Never_ trust the time/date you get from the client.